# Is there such a phrase as 'know someone do(es) something'?

Tags: phrases

Is there such a phrase as 'know someone do(es) something'? I mean, not as an ellipses version of 'know **that** someone do(es) something'. More concretely, is the following sentence correct?

> How is he supposed to know about *somebody he didn't even **know existed*** a minute ago?

Comment: Have you done any research about this?

Comment: An alternative to "know" might be "be aware of", depending on context and precise meaning.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah. The phrase not as an ellipses version of 'know that someone do(es) something' was found in neither dictionaries nor corpus.

Comment: Your parse is wrong. That sentence of yours does not contain: know someone does something. "to know someone exists" is the right parse.

Comment: This question should belong to *english.stackexchange*. Can anyone help to move it there?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the sentence:

> How is he supposed to know about somebody he didn't even know existed a minute ago?

is grammatically valid. I would also say that there is an implied "*that*", making the full implied version:

> How is he supposed to know about somebody **that** he didn't even know existed a minute ago?

It is in my view meaningless to speak of a version of this sentence that does not imply "that", the implication is made by the grammatical form.

The fuller version of the quoted sentence would be:

> How is he supposed to know about somebody **that** he didn't even know existed a minute ago?

Comment: There's a 'that' because of 'he didn't even know somebody (to?) exist'. That is, 'that' is from the subordinate clause. But what about *know somebody do something*?

Comment: @Michael I think *know somebody do something* is in effect a shorted form of  *know **that** somebody does something*

Comment: Try putting this 'that' into the quoted sentence, and you may find the sentence is weird.

Comment: @Michael I don't think it is weird. See the edited version of the answer.

Comment: But you have two 'that' to insert into the sentence. One is from 'somebody *that*', which is used to modify 'somebody'. The other is from 'know *that* someone do something', which follows 'know'.